# strtotime doesnt work with microseconds

Tags: php, strtotime

The `strtotime` function does not seem to be working when attempting to convert a string containing microseconds into a unix timestamp. I don't care about keeping the microseconds in the unix timestamp.

Example:

```
$date = '2017-03-21-10:58:01.7888';
echo strtotime($date); // always outputs 0
```

Comment: Obviously `strtotime` doesn't understand format of the string.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out. However, I didn't see this particular question asked on Stack Overflow so I figured I'd add it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The format with microseconds is not supported by PHP, see the [list of compound formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) (date and time).  You have to convert it to a supported format.  If the timestamp is guaranteed to use this format, you can split it at the dot and then use the first part to obtain the timestamp without microseconds:

```
echo strtotime(split(".", $data)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [these tests](https://3v4l.org/RuIOJ) and the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-changelog), the problem is the dash between the date and the time:

> 5.0.0    Microseconds began to be allowed, but they are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
I had the same problem and came up with this solution:

function strtotimeMicro($str)
{
    $secs = (string) strtotime($str);
    $t = new DateTimeImmutable($str);
    $micro = $t->format("u");
    $ts = $secs.$micro;
    return (int) $ts;
}

$date = '2017-03-21 10:58:01.7888';
echo strtotimeMicro($date); // returns 1490090281788800
```